# A question on derivatives of bounded signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been reading the following theorem, which is used to prove Lebesgue's Fundamental Theorem of Calculus ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure):

---

[image]

---

The thoerem is quite intuitive but I am having an enormous difficulty understanding the second direction of the proof below, namely the proof that (ii) implies (i):

[image]

Specifically, I do not understand why $|v(x,y]| < | F(x) - F(y)|$ and why $|v(\left\{a\right\})| \leq |v(I)|$ as bounded signed measures even with the absolute value need not be monotone. The book is known to contain typos so I would not be surprised if something is off here. I would be grateful if someone could take a look and clarify these points.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, those are mistakes. Well, the second point holds, but it does not follow *immediately* from $(ii)$.

By the definition of $F$ and the additivity of (signed) measures, we have

$$F(y) - F(x) = \nu\bigl((-\infty,y]\bigr) - \nu\bigl((-\infty,x]\bigr) = \nu\bigl((x,y]\bigr).$$

We still get $\bigl\lvert \nu\bigl((x,y]\bigr)\bigr\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon (y-x)$ for $x < a \leqslant y$ and $y-x < \delta$, though.

And in the considered situation we have $\nu(\{a\}) = 0$, whence the inequality $\lvert\nu(\{a\})\rvert \leqslant \lvert \nu(I)\rvert$ follows. Since $\{a\} = \bigcap (a - 1/n,a+1/n)$, we have

$$\nu(\{a\}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \nu\bigl((a-1/n,a+1/n)\bigr),$$

and for large enough $n$, $(ii)$ gives us $\bigl\lvert\nu\bigl((a-1/n,a+1/n)\bigr)\bigr\rvert < \varepsilon \cdot\frac{2}{n}$, so that implies $\nu(\{a\}) = 0$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!